# Semigroup instace for Data.Map

Tags: haskell, semigroup

I'm not sure how to write the semigroup instance for this map newtype:

```hs
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

newtype mymap = MyMap (Map Int String)

instance Semigroup (MyMap k v) where
    MyMap a <> MyMap b = Map.compose a b
```

error:

```
    • Expected kind ‘k -> k1 -> *’, but ‘MyMap’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Semigroup’, namely ‘(MyMap k v)’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Semigroup (MyMap k v)’
  |
6 | instance Semigroup (MyMap k v) where
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

I thought that `MyMap (Map Int String)` would have kind `* -> * -> *` as it takes two types (Int and String) and returns a mymap type

Thanks!

Comment: Something of kind `* -> * -> *` is something that can be applied to two types. So if `MyMap (Map Int String)` had that kind we could get a type by writing `MyMap (Map Int String) SomeType1 SomeType2`. This is not the case. Actually `MyMap` is already a type, so it has kind `*`, and `MyMap (Map Int String)` is a kind error on its own (we can't apply anything to a type). When in doubt, comment out the last part of the code (so that it compiles) and use `:k MyMap` in GHCi to see its kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your datatype capitalized

```
newtype MyMap = MkMyMap (Map Int String)
```

Type `MyMap` has no arguments, notice that I renamed the constructor `MkMyMap` to disambiguate between them:

```
instance Semigroup MyMap where
  MkMyMap a <> MkMyMap b = MkMyMap (Map.compose a b)
```

`Map.compose` will not work as a semigroup operation unless the map has type `Map A A`:

```
compose :: Ord b => Map b c -> Map a b -> Map a c
```

Let's see what happens when the first argument is `Map Int String`:

```
compose :: Map Int String -> Map a Int -> Map a String
```

If we are returning `Map Int String` as well, it forces the second argument to be `Map Int Int`

```
compose :: Map Int String -> Map Int Int -> Map Int String
```

There is a template for how maps can be defined, using a Monoid to accumulate conflicts: [MonoidalMap key a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoidal-containers-0.6.3.0/docs/Data-Map-Monoidal.html).

```hs
newtype MyMap = MkMyMap (Map Int String)
  deriving
  newtype IsList

  deriving
  stock Show

  -- >> :set -XOverloadedLists
  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"twotveir")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int String -- (<>) = unionWith (++)
```

This unions the two Maps using the `Semigroup String` for the value of every duplicate key. If we used a different Semigroup instance [`Semigroup.First String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:First) then the first key is chosen:

```
  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"two")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Semigroup.First String) -- (<>) = union
                                               --      = unionWith const
                                               --      = unionWith \a _ -> a
```

and the last key is chosen if we use `Semigroup.Last String`.

```
  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"tveir")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Semigroup.Last String) -- (<>) = unionWith \_ b -> b
```

There are also other combinations, some of which are rather strange. For example using [Applicative lifting (`Ap`)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap):

```
  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"tttttwwwwwooooo")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Ap [] (Semigroup.First Char)) -- (<>) = unionWith (liftA2 \a _ -> a)
                                                     --      = unionWith (<*)

  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"tveirtveirtveir")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Ap [] (Semigroup.Last Char)) -- (<>) = unionWith (liftA2 \_ b -> b)
                                                    --      = unionWith (*>)

  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"two")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Ap ZipList (Semigroup.First Char)) -- (<>) = unionWith (zipWith \a _ -> a)

  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"tve")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Ap ZipList (Semigroup.Last Char)) -- (<>) = unionWith (zipList \_ b -> b)

  -- >> [(2, "two"), (0, "zero")] <> [(1, "einn"), (2, "tveir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(0,"zero"),(1,"einn"),(2,"two")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Max String) -- (<>) = unionWith max

  -- >> [(4, "four")] <> [(4, "fjórir")] :: MyMap
  -- MkMyMap (fromList [(4,"foór")])
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via MonoidalMap Int (Ap ZipList (Max Char)) -- (<>) = unionWith (zipWith max)
```